# HC-05 Bluetooth RF transmit power

Tags: power, rf, bluetooth, transmission

The datasheet of the HC-05 Bluetooth module says the RF transmit power is up to +4 dBm RF, but I think that is for boundary value conditions.

I am planning to use the it at a data rate of 100 kbps and distance will be up to 2-3 metres only, so will the transmit power decrease and if it decreases what will the value of RF transmit power be?

We are using micro hard radio PMDDL2450 and we don't want the HC-05 Bluetooth module to interfere with the radio because both operate at the same frequencies.

Comment: Why have you reposted a virtual copy of your previous question? [HC-05 Bluetooth RF Transmit power at 2 metres and 100kbps rate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/496240/hc-05-bluetooth-rf-transmit-power-at-2-metres-and-100kbps-rate) AND, in that previous question, failed to provide the information you were asked to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** avoid two devices, which are using the same frequency band, to interfere with each other. You also cannot (and should not) try to solve that by increasing the transmitted power.

You are probably unaware of the fact that Bluetooth is **designed** to be **robust** against interference from other devices using the same frequency band. Bluetooth does this by changing frequency all the time and simply re-transmitting packets that got lost. So you should not worry about this and first see what you get.

It is unclear to me how that "micro hard" radio will deal with any interference.

Do realize that multiple devices **can** work in the same frequency band provided that they "take turns" when using it. Some high data-rate connections (Like WiFi and probably that "micro hard" device as well) take up a large part of the bandwidth, leaving little room for other devices. When that happens datarates will drop as packets have to be re-send. That hinders efficient use of the bandwidth.

Comment: full bandwidth of that micro hard thing is 8 MHz...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the HC-05 will do a lot of power control, or at least not a very fine-grained power control. In any case, the amount it'll be reduced can't be told, and is probably a proprietary secret of the bluetooth IC manufacturer.

> We are using micro hard radio PMDDL2450 and that we don't want the Bluetooth module HC-05 to interfere with the radio because both operate at same frequencies.

It will interfere, there's nothing you can do about that; and, it will be a relatively strong burst interferer; I'd doubt you can remedy that. That doesn't need to be a problem – with channel coding and things like ARQ, you'll not necessarily lose data.

Also, this is an ISM band, you have *no* control at all about which other interferers might be in your environment.

Also, you say

> both operate at same frequencies.

but that's not necessarily true. The FCC documentation of the PMDDL2450 shows it only uses 4 or 8 MHz of bandwidth:

[image: spectrum plot]

and you can put that at one band edge, and configure your bluetooth device to avoid that.

Also, the device says it's pretty resilient to bad SINR, so maybe you simply needn't worry about Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the interferers, and absorbers, etc, here is a Tx power prediction:

-174 dBm/rtHz   electron noise floor

+60dB   1,000,000 Hrtz bandwidth approximately

0db error correction coding gatn

+10dB signal_noise_ratio for 0.1% bit_error_rate (depends on single/double BW)

+4 dB antenna matching; first transistor noise floor(figure);

ZERO dB Rx antenna gain

+62 dB PathLoss (radiation spreading in square-law between Tx and Rx antennas; 22dB + 10*log10[ (distance/wavelength)^2];  15 meters distance is 100 wavelength;

ZERO dB Tx antenna gain

1dB loss from TX power transistor out to antenna

================= total

-37 dBm, which is 3dB stronger than -40dBm

With 0dBm across 50 ohms being 0.632 volts PeakPeak, we know -40dB is 100X lower in voltage at 0.00632 Vpp. The 3dB stronger (1.414) I will let you compute.

Comment: Not sure how this is even close to an answer to the question.